# Windows wouldn't connect to wifi networks after using Kali

Tags: linux, windows, networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux

I had this issue in two different laptops and I could not find a proper answer till now. My wifi was going well until I decided to run a live version of kali and play there a little bit. I used aircrack-ng (and of course turned the monitor mode on and off again) but when I boot back to windows I can not connect to any wifi networks. It shows all nearby networks but it would not connect to any.

I made sure that monitor mode is turned off and it is back to managed mode. I turned wlan down and up again using `ifconfig wlan0 down` ,`ifconfig wlan0 up`, 
uninstalled the driver on windows and reinstalled it again but in vain.

The weird thing is that wlan is working fine on Kali Linux and I can connect to any networks, switch between monitor and managed mode smoothly but when I run back to windows I cannot connect.

Comment: You using Kali and you being unable to connect to a network isn't related.  Something else is going on.

Comment: @ramhound Thanks for your help but the same thing happens on two different devices just after doing that makes me think it's strongly related